# resourceGroupField multiple levels

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar allow possibility to group resource using **resourceGroupField**.
[As it describe here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceGroupField).

But it allow only one group level and I need to have multiple level (2).

For exemple :

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarMultipleGroups, {
  resourceGroupField: 'group, subGroup',
  resources: [
    // # Group a
    // ## Subgroup z
    {id: '1', group: 'a', subGroup: 'z', title: 'Resource a-z-1'},
    {id: '2', group: 'a', subGroup: 'z', title: 'Resource a-z-2'},
    // ## Subgroup y
    {id: '3', group: 'a', subGroup: 'y', title: 'Resource a-y-3'},
    // # Group b
    // ## Subgroup x
    {id: '4', group: 'b', subGroup: 'x', title: 'Resource b-x-4'}
  ]
});
```

But  `resourceGroupField: 'group, subGroup'` doesn't  work.

Do you know a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: It's not possible so all you can do is request it - https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features